How to center a series of text width a fixed width that can automatically linebreak and underline it?
I want to center a series of text width a fixed width that can automatically linebreak and underline it, just like the following effect:

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \l_center_box:nn #1#2
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {#1}
    \dim_add:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {0.6em}
    \makebox[0cm][l]{\rule[-.8ex]{\l_tmpa_dim}{.5 pt}}
    {\hbox_to_wd:nn {\l_tmpa_dim} { \hfil #2 \hfil }}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\l_center_box:nn {8cm}
{
  This~is~a~test~for~the~question...
}
\par\vspace*{1em}
\l_center_box:nn {8cm}
{
  This~is~a~test~for~the~question...This~is~a~test~for~the~question...
  This~is~a~test~for~the~question...This~is~a~test~for~the~question...
}
\par\vspace*{1em}
What~I~want~is
\par\vspace*{1em}
\l_center_box:nn {8cm}
{
  This~is~a~test~for~the~question...This~is~a~test~for~the~qu-
}\par
\l_center_box:nn {8cm}
{
  estion...This~is~a~test~for~the~question...This~is~a~test~for
}\par
\l_center_box:nn {8cm}
{
  the~question...
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


Are you ok with the qu-estion line break? Please advise.

Why there is the expl3 tag? I see nothing related to it in the answers. Fortunately.

Provided lines are “normal” (not too high or deep), the following code dismantles the built paragraph line by line and adds a rule.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\underlinequestion}[2]{% #1 = width, #2 = text
  \global\setbox1=\box\voidb@x
  \setbox0=\vbox{
    \hsize=#1\relax
    \parindent=0pt
    \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
    \rightskip=0pt plus -1fil
    \parfillskip=0pt plus 2fil
    #2\par
    \loop
    \setbox2=\lastbox
    \unless\ifvoid2
    \global\setbox1=\vbox{\hbox to\hsize{\strut\unhbox2}\hrule\vskip1pt\unvbox1}
    \unskip\unpenalty
    \repeat
  }
  \box1
}

\begin{document}

\underlinequestion{8cm}{
  This is a test for the question...
}

\bigskip

\underlinequestion{8cm}{
  This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...
  This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...
}

\end{document}


Hyphenation is done automatically. With
\underlinequestion{9cm}{
  This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...
  This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...
}

we'd get


+1 for providing a solution that doesn't create a qu-estion line break/hyphenation point. :-)

@Mico Hyphenation is done normally, as witnessed by the added example.

@egreg Great! But... there still exists a small bug: If I set a token list with 'This is a test for the question...x4', then it will not auto line break: \tl_set:Ne \l_my_tmpa_tl {This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...}, then \underlinequestion{ .75\linewidth } { \l_my_tmpa_tl }, even though I use \exp_args:Ne, it also works unproperly :-(

@Skyrmion For starters, you shouldn't be using expl3 at the document level. Next, if you do, you should be aware that spaces are ignored after ExplSyntaxOn. Finally, I tested it and it works as expected, provided spaces are input correctly. Where's the problem with your test? That . is not considered a letter, so TeX abandons hyphenation until it finds some space.

@egreg Oh, I fogot to add ~ between words The problem is solved. But, I found another problem, just like the t option of \begin{aligned}[t], it couldn't aligned by the top, for example: This is the title: \underlinequestion {.6\linewidth} { This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...}, the first line of it couldn't align to This is the title.

@Skyrmion It's always the problem with underspecified questions… How do you think we can read your mind? Anyway, replace \global\setbox1=\vbox{ with \global\setbox1=\vtop{

I show another approach: First, we print the paragraph. Second, we return back and draw the rules over the paragraph in the \loop. The number of rules is given by the \prevgraf register.
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\centeredpar{%
    \parindent=0pt
    \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
    \rightskip=0pt plus -1fil
    \parfillskip=0pt plus 2fil
}
\def\putrules{\par
   \dimen0=\prevdepth
   \tmpnum=\prevgraf
   \nointerlineskip \vbox to-\dimen0{\vss
      \loop
          \kern\baselineskip
          \kern-.4pt \hrule width\hsize
          \advance\tmpnum by-1
          \ifnum\tmpnum>0 \repeat
      \kern-.7ex
   }
}

{\hsize=8cm \centeredpar
  This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...
  This is a test for the question...This is a test for the question...
\putrules}

\bye


You could use TikZ:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner xsep=0pt]
\node[text width=9cm,align=none,pattern={Lines[distance=12pt,yshift=-2pt]}] {
  \leftskip=0cm plus 0.5fil 
  \rightskip=0cm plus -0.5fil
  \parfillskip=0cm plus 1fil
  This is a test for the question... 
  This is a test for the question...\par};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



It's not elegant, actually, I will use it in a tabular

@Skyrmion ... in this case I would suggest to use the nicematrix package. It's cells are automatically tikz nodes and you would just have to add the background pattern.
